# Html table sorting using JavaScript or jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting, sequence

[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6JgRm.png) is a image of my sample code. I want to sort this table data, column wise when click the each sort button in top in the table. This table contains PHP also.

---

**Number** 
            **Date** 

        

        
            Three
            
        

        
            Five
            
        

        
            One
            
        

        
            Four
            
        

        
            Two

---

When user click on sort button, **entire row should be sorted** in acs or desc according to clicked column's data. Column  contains words and column 2 contains dates.
Anyone knows that help me please....

Thanks

Comment: Your question is unclear what you want to sort data as row wise or column wise?

Comment: Lahiru don't upload the image of code. Just copy paste code with the code indentation in the text field bar.

Comment: Thank you for guiding me to use stackoverflow. I am a new one to here. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Can you check jquery datatable plugin. That supports sorting, expanding columns for a table. Please see the link 
https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/table_sorting.html

Answer (score 0):

I have used the [tablesorter](http://tablesorter.com/docs/) jQuery plugin. It is a light weight and a very good plugin for your needs. I think this will suits to your need.

Answer (score 0):

I would start with this:
https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_sort_table
It's works just fine, and doesn't require even jQuery, let's alone jQuery plugins. 
It's obviously, you should adapt code to sort with different columns names (not just for "Name"), but is easy enough.

Answer (score 0):

You can use table-sorter (a client-side table sorting) and sort the table once after the page loaded. After that each of the columns is sortable by clicking the column header (It is in pure javascript and doesn't need jquery):

http://tablesorter.com/docs